# How to validate a number in a textfield and check security?

Tags: php, validation, security, isnumeric

I made a little PHP Scripting for checking the input in a form textfielt if
a.) it is a number
b.) if it is secure

I tried it with a function

```
<?php
function checkSecurity($glob) {
if (is_numeric($glob)) {
    $value = htmlspecialchars($glob);
    $value = trim($glob);
    return $value;
}
else
{  
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>Wrong Input</p>";
    die;
}  
}
```

My answer: is it necessary to check the security with *htmlspecialchars()* and *trim()* or isn`t it just enough to use *is_numeric()*

Thanks a lot
Mario

Comment: Well, if it's numeric, that already means it doesn't contain any special characters or whitespace, so `htmlspecialchars` and `trim` are kind of redundant.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` should only be used when you're displaying something on a web page, and it might contain characters that are special in HTML like `<` or `&`, to prevent XSS. You generally shouldn't use it while passing the value around internally within the script.

Answer (score 0):

- If input is numeric, neither htmlspecialchars nor trim would do anything.
- Line 4 in your code is pointless, because the next line overwrites `$value`.
- `htmlspecialchars()` is an _output_encoding function anyway, you don't usually want to use it on input.
- When used correctly, `htmlspecialchars()` protects against *some types of* XSS. This will not make anything secure, not even against XSS in general, let alone oher vulnerabilities.
- In most cases, you can't implement a generic "checkSecurity" function for your application to handle all input validation. If this was possible, why would your framework not do it? (Ok, .net does to some extent, but it's arguable whether that is overall positive or negative, considering the false sense of security it gives to developers.)
- You should never concatenate html from strings, or build html responses in variables (applicable to both server and client side). You need a template engine if this ever happens.